# Append float in a list with for in Python

Tags: python, list, append

I'm trying to build a function that multiplies the itens of each vector and return a vector with those numbers,but I'm having problem to append the multiplication.

Example:

-input:

```
vec1 = np.array([-2.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0])

vec2 = np.array([-16.2, 87.8, -7.199999999999999, -52.2, -12.2])

list_mult(vec1,vec2)
```

-output :

```
[ 32.4 -87.8  -0.  -52.2 -24.4]
```

-Here is my code and the output error:

```
import numpy as np

def list_mult(v1,v2):
    result = list()
    for i in v1: 
        for j in v2:
            result.append(v1[i] * v2[j])
    return result
```

output:

````
      4     for i in v1:
      5         for j in v2:
----> 6             result.append(v1[i] * v2[j])
      7     return result

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not numpy.float64
```
````

Comment: Here `i` and `j` are the `v1[i]`, I mean `i` and `j` are not indices but the numbers them selves (-16.2, 87.8, -7.199999999999999, -52.2, -12.2) so you need `result.append(i * j)` only.

Comment: np.multiply(vec1, vec2)

Comment: `[i * j for i in v1 for j in v2]`

Comment: You're using numpy, which has that functionality built-in. You can simply do `vec1 * vec2` which will do a element-wise multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating the elements, but while accessing you are passing the elements as index. So you are getting the error.

Change the following line

```
 In [38]: import numpy as np
    ...:
    ...: def list_mult(v1,v2):
    ...:     result = list()
    ...:     for idx1,i in enumerate(v1):
    ...:         for idx2,j in enumerate(v2):
    ...:             if (idx1 == idx2):
    ...:                 result.append(i * j)
    ...:     return result
    ...:
    ...:

In [39]: list_mult(vec1,vec2)
Out[39]: [32.4, -87.8, -0.0, -52.2, -24.4]
```

More elegant solution would be to use the `np.multiply` function of numpy package.

```
In [37]: np.multiply(vec1,vec2)
Out[37]: array([ 32.4, -87.8,  -0. , -52.2, -24.4])
```

Comment: Initially made the same mistake, the nested loops will generate 16 values instead of 4 like OP wanted :)

Comment: When i use the first  one its returns me the following list : [32.4, -175.6, 14.399999999999999, 104.4, 24.4, 16.2, -87.8, 7.199999999999999, 52.2, 12.2, -0.0, 0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -16.2, 87.8, -7.199999999999999, -52.2, -12.2, -32.4, 175.6, -14.399999999999999, -104.4, -24.4]

Comment: because its doing a cross product of two list.

Comment: updated the answer but would recommend to use the multiple function of numpy package as it is more optimized.